# How to simplify animation transaction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In 2D scene, I have 3 idle states and 3 walk states (each idle/walk state has 3 direction sub state).

I know I can make transactions in animator.

My question is, how to simplify transaction? For example, `idle_front` state has 5 transactions to other states (idle_back, idle_right, walk_front, walk_back, walk_right), now if I want to add an attack state, also with 3 direction sub state, the transaction lines makes me crazy.

**My solution**

I have tried using `animator.Play()` to play animation, but when switch to attack state, there is a problem.

The invocation of idle state play is in `FixedUpdate()` event function, after response to the attack key press event (to play attack animation), only little frames of attack is played, it is soon replaced by idle animation.

How can I implement similar effect of a trigger, to play the whole attack animation? Or is there any way to simplify transactions, and continue to use a trigger?

Example code is here

```cs
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (moveInput.y == 0)
    {
        switch (moveInput.x)
        {
            case < 0:
                animator.SetInteger(Direction, (int) MovingDirection.Left);
                animator.Play("player_walk_right");
                spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
                break;
            case > 0:
                animator.SetInteger(Direction, (int) MovingDirection.Right);
                animator.Play("player_walk_right");
                spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (moveInput.y)
        {
            case < 0:
                animator.SetInteger(Direction, (int) MovingDirection.Down);
                animator.Play("player_walk_front");
                break;
            case > 0:
                animator.SetInteger(Direction, (int) MovingDirection.Up);
                animator.Play("player_walk_back");
                break;
        }
    }
}

void OnFire()
{
    switch (animator.GetInteger(Direction))
    {
        case (int) MovingDirection.Up:
            animator.Play("player_attack_back");
            break;
        case (int) MovingDirection.Down:
            animator.Play("player_attack_front");
            break;
        case (int) MovingDirection.Left:
            animator.Play("player_attack_right");
            spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
            break;
        case (int) MovingDirection.Right:
            animator.Play("player_attack_right");
            spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to stop moving while the attack animation is playing. To know when the animation is end, one way is using events https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationEventsOnImportedClips.html

First you need to add an event near the end of the animation, let's name it `OnAttackEnd`.

<sup>NOTE! To ensure the script can receive the event, the script and the animator must be attached on the same GameObject.</sup>

In the script add a boolean field to indicate if attack anim is playing and the `OnAttackEnd` callback.

```
bool _isAttackAnimPlaying;

void OnAttackEnd()
    => _isAttackAnimPlaying = false;
```

In `OnFire` method, set the boolean field to true, and in `FixedUpdate` method check the value.

```
void OnFire()
{
    switch (animator.GetInteger(Direction))
    {
        case (int) MovingDirection.Up:
            animator.Play("player_attack_back");
            _isAttackAnimPlaying = true;
        ....
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(!_isAttackAnimPlaying)
    {
       .....
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it by using animation event: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html

Comment: It can keep moving, just check if attack animation is playing before playing idle/walk